# File writing command in pexpect not behaving as I thought it would

Tags: python, linux, command-line, pexpect

There is a process that i can run from the command line which writes data to a file continuously until i tell it to stop, and can be accessed (read) while the process is running.

However, if I run the same command through pexpect, the file stays empty (although can be read) until I stop the pexpect instance.  Only then will the file fill up with the data.

Is this just a feature of pexpect or am I doing something wrong here?

pexpect command:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('airodump-ng', ['-a', '-w', '/root/Desktop/TEST', '--output-format', 'csv', INTERFACE])
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use `pexpect`?

Comment: I added the code above.  So when i run that code the file (/root/desktop/test) will fill only when i exit the program, but when i run the command manually in a terminal the file is written to instantaneously..

Comment: Do you really need to interact with `airodump-ng` using `pexpect`?  Or could you simply use the `subprocess` module?  I wonder if `pexpect` is causing things to block in the absence of any `expect` or `interact` statements.

Comment: It sounds to me like a buffered or unbuffered output.

Comment: Is there something else you needed, or was this enough help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used `airodump-ng`; if it is a fire and forget exercise (no interaction), you should be using `pexpect.run()` for non-interactive tasks such as `ls -la`

```
results = pexpect.run('ls -la')
```

If you need interaction, just put your args in one string...

```
child = pexpect.spawn('airodump-ng -a -w /root/Desktop/TEST --output-format csv %s' % INTERFACE)
```